# How to move the search text box to the extreme right and Categories drop down to the left in html

Tags: html, css

Here is the code: I have aligned the code accordingly. This is the issue which is happening now, please see the [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hUZCA.jpg). How do I move the search box to the extreme right and the categories drop down box to the left? Both have to be aligned in the same line.

CSS for search:

```
    .tfbutton {
            margin: 0;
            padding: 5px 15px;
            font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
            font-size:14px;
            outline: none;
            cursor: pointer;
            text-align: center;
            text-decoration: none;
            color: #ffffff;
            border: solid 1px #0076a3; border-right:0px;
            background: #0095cd;
            background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(#00adee), to(#0078a5));
            background: -moz-linear-gradient(top,  #00adee,  #0078a5);
            border-top-right-radius: 5px 5px;
            border-bottom-right-radius: 5px 5px; `
```

CSS for the "Categories" drop down:

```
    <style type="text/css">

      ul {list-style: none;padding: 5px;margin: 2px;}
      ul li {display: block;position: relative;float:left;border:solid 1px #0076a3;}
      li ul {display: none;}
      ul li a {display: block;background: #ffffff;padding: 5px 10px 5px 10px;text-decoration: none;
               white-space: nowrap;color: #0076a3;border: solid 1px #0076a3;}
      ul li a:hover {background: #0095cd;}
      li:hover ul {display: block; position: absolute;}
      li:hover li {float: none;}
      li:hover a {background: #ffffff;}
      li:hover li a:hover {background: #ffffff;border: solid 1px #0076a3;}
      #drop-nav li ul li {border-top: 0px;}
    </style>
```

Expected: Both the categories and search has to be in the same line, categories  drop down in the left and the search in the right corner.

Comment: For your future questions... Try to use a fiddle in order to show people what you've done so far instead of just writing code here. That will help others to work on your issue quicker.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use CSS `float: left` and `float: right`.

Comment: If i use the command,float:right; for the search button ,it does not work according to the required.The search button is displayed first and then textbox.

Comment: Can you post your `HTML`?

Comment: <!-- HTML for SEARCH BAR -->
 <div id="tfheader">
  <form id="tfnewsearch" method="get" action="http://www.google.com">
          <input type="text" class="tftextinput" name="q" size="21" maxlength="120"><input type="submit" value="search" class="tfbutton">
  </form>
  <div class="tfclear"></div>
 </div>

Comment: <!-- HTML for  categories drop down-->
 <ul id="drop-nav">
 
  <li><a href="#">Categories</a>
  
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#">Talk Show </a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Technology</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Sports</a></li>
   <li><a href="#">Business</a></li>
   <li><a href="#">Science</a></li>
   <li><a href="#">Travel</a></li>
   <li><a href="#">Food & Dining</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>

Comment: Sorry I meant edit your question and add it there (so it is formatted properly).  Also, include CSS using `float`.  See Fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/d1ccyL7g/.

Comment: Start with my basic float left/right fiddle and incrementally add your HTML until it breaks.  You should be able to narrow down what is causing the issue.  I started this here: https://jsfiddle.net/ugsz4sh4/ - you can see the basic menu and search appear as you expect.  Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

well `float: left/right` seems like the best but if that doesnt work try

```
margin-left: 100%;
```

and add your HTML to the question please

Comment: the above link is the fiddle link and if i use margin nor float command,it separates the search button from the text field,

Comment: Are they in the same div? If not put them in a div and float/margin the div

Comment: if i put margin as 100% the search button and the text input box moves to different directions...

Comment: Two things make sure you put margin left and make sure they're in the same div and you might have to change it to like 90%